# Refreshing Data in A Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny application which connects to 4 different SQL databases and 3 different APIs to download data. I have scheduled this operation of data collection through an R script which is executed every 4 hours. The script stores the data as an Rdata file comprising of 18 different dataframes.

The `global.R` file of the shiny application loads this data using `load("data/data.Rdata")` when the application is launched and the application runs fine.

However, in order to refresh the data, I presume `reactivePoll` is what I would need. But am not sure how to get it going. This is what I have tried in the `global.R` file which doesn't work:

```
  reactivePoll(14400000,session = NULL,
               checkFunc = function() {
                 if (file.exists("data/data.Rdata"))
                   file.info("data/data.Rdata")$mtime[1]
                 else
                   ""
               },
                 valueFunc = function() {
                 load("data/data.Rdata")
               })
```

Comment: You best to do that via a `cron job` or `Task Scheduler`. In order for `reactivePoll` to do that your app cant be idle, which isnt great implementation

Comment: @PorkChop downloading of the data is already happening through a `cron job`. I just can't figure out how to update the data in the Shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using `load` to get the data which puts the data into memory as side-effect. The example of reactivePoll uses a function that returns the values.

A discussion about combining load with reactive is available here -> [Reading an RData file into Shiny Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064038/reading-an-rdata-file-into-shiny-application)