# Shiny: Global Reactive Dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I have a global data-frame (it would be defined in Global.R) that is constructed by querying a postgre database. This data-frame needs to be shared across multiple sessions.

Now in the UI, of each session, I need to display a data table with the contents of this data frame. I also have a radioButton object so that the user can change the value of a field, call it `decision` in the data-frame for a given row, and I would like the corresponding line in the data table to be displayed or not (i.e. display the data-frame row as a line in the datatable if `decision == 0` only)

**Problem:** 
I would like the line in the datatable to be *reactively hidden/displayed* according to the value the user gives to `decision` and I would like that to happen **across multiple sessions**

So if there are 2 users and user_1 changes the value of `decision` for row `a` from 0 (displayed) to 1 (hidden), I would like that row to be reactively hidden in the datatables of BOTH user_1 AND user_2 without either of them having to refresh or press an actionButton.

What would be the *best way to go about this?*

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# global data-frame
df <<- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], decision = 0)

update_decision_value <- function (id, dec) {
  df[df$id == id, "decision"] <<- dec
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('select_id'),
  uiOutput('decision_value'),
  dataTableOutput('my_table')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filter.data <- reactive({
    df %>% 
      filter(decision == 0)
  })

  output$select_id <- renderUI({
    selectInput('selected_id', "ID:", choices = df$id)
  })

  output$decision_value <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(
      'decision_value',
      "Decision Value:",
      choices = c("Display" = 0, "Hide" = 1),
      selected = df[df$id == input$selected_id, "decision"]
    )
  })

  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    filter.data()
  })

  observeEvent(input$decision_value, {
    update_decision_value(input$selected_id, input$decision_value)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: One way would be to saveRDS the variable to disk, have one session commit changes to that file (block other session from trying the same) and use a reactiveFileReader to poll the changes in all other sessions. Maybe there are better ways to go.

Comment: Another way would be to save the changes in the database and all sessions can read/write from the same table (using e.g. reactivePoll).

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal , the reactivePoll seams like a good idea (I need to save the changes in the database anyways). I'm just unsure as to what would be the most efficient way to implement the checkFunc argument of reactivePoll in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

# global data-frame
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], decision = 0, another_col = LETTERS[1:10])
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my.db", overwrite = FALSE)

if (!"df" %in% dbListTables(con)) {
  dbWriteTable(con, "df", df)
}

# drop global data-frame
rm("df")

update_decision_value <- function (id, dec) {
  dbExecute(con, sprintf("UPDATE df SET decision = '%s' WHERE id = '%s';", dec, id))
}

ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("shiny_session"),
                uiOutput('select_id'),
                uiOutput('decision_value'),
                dataTableOutput('my_table'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$shiny_session <- renderText(paste("Shiny session:", session$token))

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    if (!is.null(con)) {
      dbDisconnect(con)
      con <<- NULL # avoid warning; sqlite uses single connection for multiple shiny sessions
    }
  })

  df_ini <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT id, decision FROM df;")
  all_ids <- df_ini$id

  df <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 100,
    session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      req(con)
      df_current <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT id, decision FROM df;")
      if (all(df_current == df_ini)) {
        return(TRUE)
      }
      else{
        df_ini <<- df_current
        return(FALSE)
      }
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      dbReadTable(con, "df")
    }
  )

  filter.data <- reactive({
    df() %>%
      filter(decision == 0)
  })

  output$select_id <- renderUI({
    selectInput('selected_id', "ID:", choices = all_ids)
  })

  output$decision_value <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(
      'decision_value',
      "Decision Value:",
      choices = c("Display" = 0, "Hide" = 1),
      selected = df()[df()$id == input$selected_id, "decision"]
    )
  })

  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    filter.data()
  })

  observeEvent(input$decision_value, {
    update_decision_value(input$selected_id, input$decision_value)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit ------------------------------------

Updated version which reduces load on the db by avoiding to compare the entire table and instead only searches shiny-session-wise unkown changes (taking into account a ms-timestamp, which is updated for every decision change):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

# global data-frame
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], decision = 0, last_mod=as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000, another_col = LETTERS[1:10])
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my.db", overwrite = FALSE)

if (!"df" %in% dbListTables(con)) {
  dbWriteTable(con, "df", df)
}

# drop global data-frame
rm("df")

update_decision_value <- function (id, dec) {
  dbExecute(con, sprintf("UPDATE df SET decision = '%s', last_mod = '%s' WHERE id = '%s';", dec, as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000, id))
}

ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("shiny_session"),
                uiOutput('select_id'),
                uiOutput('decision_value'),
                dataTableOutput('my_table'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$shiny_session <- renderText(paste("Shiny session:", session$token))

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    if (!is.null(con)) {
      dbDisconnect(con)
      con <<- NULL # avoid warning; sqlite uses single connection for multiple shiny sessions
    }
  })

  df_session <- dbReadTable(con, "df")
  all_ids <- df_session$id
  last_known_mod <- max(df_session$last_mod)

  df <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 100,
    session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      req(con)
      df_changed_rows <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE last_mod > '%s';", last_known_mod))
      if(!nrow(df_changed_rows) > 0){
        return(TRUE)
      }
      else{
        changed_ind <- match(df_changed_rows$id, df_session$id)
        df_session[changed_ind, ] <<- df_changed_rows
        last_known_mod <<- max(df_session$last_mod)
        return(FALSE)
      }
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      return(df_session)
    }
  )

  filter.data <- reactive({
    df() %>%
      filter(decision == 0)
  })

  output$select_id <- renderUI({
    selectInput('selected_id', "ID:", choices = all_ids)
  })

  output$decision_value <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(
      'decision_value',
      "Decision Value:",
      choices = c("Display" = 0, "Hide" = 1),
      selected = df()[df()$id == input$selected_id, "decision"]
    )
  })

  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    filter.data()
  })

  observeEvent(input$decision_value, {
    update_decision_value(input$selected_id, input$decision_value)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In your actual code you might want to increase the `intervalMillis`. Most sql-servers won't be happy if a select is thrown at them every 100 ms. But that is something to tune according to your setup (table size etc.).