# Avoid double execution of computation that depends on updated slider value

Tags: r, shiny

**Background:** In a Shiny app, I have (i) a data-entry text area and (ii) a slider. *The slider's value and end points are updated by the data* because the slider range should be appropriate for the scale of the data. A subsequent time-consuming computation uses both the data from the text area and the value from the slider.

**The problem:** When the data are changed, the time-consuming computation executes twice, first using the *previous* value of the slider (not the updated value of the slider), and then a second time using the updated value of the slider. My intention is for it to execute only once, using the updated value of the slider not the previous value of slider.

**A minimal example:** The R code below demonstrates the problem with as small a set-up as seemed relevant. Just copy and paste into RStudio and click Run App. You'll see the output at the bottom of the screen: After a few seconds it displays 4025, and then after a few more seconds it displays 50. Click re-load to watch it again. The initial output (i.e., 4025) is irrelevant. Only the final output (i.e., 50) is intended.

**Other nuances:** The slider is on a `debounce` delay so that its motion doesn't instantly trigger the time-consuming computation. The user should be able to move the slider a bit tentatively without the computation getting triggered immediately. This is important for the app, but tangential to the double-execution problem. And the data `textAreaInput` uses an `actionButton` so that typing text doesn't instantly trigger the computation. Again, important for the app but tangential to the double-execution problem.

*Thank you in advance for suggestions!*

```r
library(shiny)
library(magrittr) # for pipe operator, %>%, used with debounce().
debounceDelay = 2000 # milliseconds

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data affect Slider, both affect Subsequent Long Computation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Data input:
      textAreaInput( inputId="dataText" , 
                     label="Type data, then click Submit:" , 
                     value="10 20 30 40" ,
                     width="200px" ,
                     height="100px" ) ,
      actionButton( inputId="dataSubmit" , 
                    label="Submit Data" ) ,
      # Slider input, to be updated by data:
      sliderInput( inputId = "slider1" ,
                   label = HTML("Constant to Add to Mean of Data 
                                (after debounce delay):") ,
                   min=3000 , max=5000 , value=4000 , 
                   round=FALSE , step=1 , ticks=FALSE )
    ) , # end sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("theOutput")
    )
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end ui fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Parse data values out of data text:
  theData = reactive({
    input$dataSubmit # establish dependency on dataSubmit button
    yText = isolate(input$dataText) # remove dependency on dataText
    y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(yText,"\\s+")[[1]]))
    if ( any(is.na(y)) | length(y) < 2 ) {
      y=c(-12.3, 45.6, 78.9) # arbitrary replacement values
      updateTextAreaInput( session ,
                           inputId="dataText" ,
                           value=paste(as.character(y),collapse=" ") )
    }
    return( y )
  }) 
  # Computation on data for using in slider update:
  upUI <- reactive({
    low = min( theData() )
    val = median( theData() )
    high = max( theData() )
    return( list( low=low , val=val , high=high ) )
  })
  # Update slider based on data values:
  observe({
    updateSliderInput( session , inputId="slider1" , 
                       min=upUI()$low , 
                       max=upUI()$high , 
                       value=upUI()$val )
  })

  # Debounce the slider value so it doesn't instantly trigger a cascade of long
  # computations
  sliderValue <- reactive({
    return( input$slider1 )
  }) %>% debounce(debounceDelay)

  # Compute output:
  output$theOutput <- renderText({
    Sys.sleep(3) # simulate lengthy computation time
    return( paste( "Time-consuming computation...
        Mean of data plus slider value: " ,
        mean(theData()) + sliderValue() ) ) 
  }) # end of renderText

} # end server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**AMENDMENT in response to initial version of reply from @ismirsehregal:**

Using the suggestion to protect the long computation by `eventReactive( input$runComp , { ...long computation... } )`, I have revised my initial script. There is no longer a need to `debounce` the slider value because the long computation is not triggered by the slider. There is also no need to have `req(theData(), sliderValue())`, as far as I can tell. I also added an `if(){}else{}` in the computation section to check for invalid text data entry. This revised script constitutes one solution to the problem.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data affect Slider, both affect Subsequent Long Computation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Data input:
      textAreaInput( inputId="dataText" , 
                     label=HTML( "<b>Type data here.</b> <small>(Must be at least two numeric values separated by whitespace.)</small>" ) , 
                     value="10 20 30 40" ,
                     width="200px" ,
                     height="100px" ) ,
      # Slider input, to be updated by data:
      sliderInput( inputId = "slider1" ,
                   label = HTML("<b>Select constant to add to mean of data.</b> <small>(Slider settings will change if data change.)</small>") ,
                   min=NA , max=NA , value=NA , 
                   round=FALSE , step=1 , ticks=FALSE ),
      HTML("<p>Click the button to start the time-consuming computation:") ,
      actionButton( inputId="runComp" , 
                    label="Start Computation" )
    ) , # end sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("theOutput")
    )
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end ui fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  theDataDefault = c(-1, 1)

  # Parse data values out of data text:
  theData = reactive({
    yText = input$dataText
    y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(yText,"\\s+")[[1]]))
    return( y )
  }) 
  # Computation on data for using in slider update:
  upUI <- reactive({
    if ( any(is.na(theData())) | length(theData()) < 2 ) {
      y = theDataDefault 
    } else {
      y = theData()
    }
    low = min( y )
    val = mean( range( y ) )
    high = max( y )
    return( list( low=low , val=val , high=high ) )
  })
  # Update slider based on data values:
  observe({
    updateSliderInput( session , inputId="slider1" , 
                       min=upUI()$low , 
                       max=upUI()$high , 
                       value=upUI()$val )
  })

  # Compute output:
  textOut <- eventReactive( input$runComp, {
    if ( any(is.na(theData())) | length(theData()) < 2 ) {
      return( "ERROR: Data must be at least two numeric values (no letters) separated by whitespace (no commas, etc.)." ) 
    } else {
      Sys.sleep(3) # simulate lengthy computation time
      return( paste( "Time-consuming computation...
                   Mean of data plus slider value: " ,
                     mean( theData()) + input$slider1 ) ) 
    }
  })

  output$theOutput <- renderText({
    textOut()
  }) 

} # end server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the wrap up. `debounce` indeed is no longer needed, dropping it increases the responsiveness of the app. Another thought that came to my mind when working on your code was that you might want to check the possbility of processing the long running computation asynchronously via library([future](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html)). Here is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420412/how-can-i-send-a-get-request-without-waiting-for-the-response/55847063#55847063)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if this meets your expectations:

The initial value for your slider now is `NA`, so that you can block the inital display via `req()`. Furthermore I isolated `theData()` in `renderText` to avoid it beeing triggered twice (only listening for changes of the slider).

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr) # for pipe operator, %>%, used with debounce().
debounceDelay = 2000 # milliseconds

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data affect Slider, both affect Subsequent Long Computation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Data input:
      textAreaInput( inputId="dataText" , 
                     label="Adapt slider data:" , 
                     value="10 20 30 40" ,
                     width="200px" ,
                     height="100px" ) ,
      # Slider input, to be updated by data:
      sliderInput( inputId = "slider1" ,
                   label = HTML("Constant to Add to Mean of Data 
                                (after debounce delay):") ,
                   min=NA , max=NA , value=NA , 
                   round=FALSE , step=1 , ticks=FALSE ),
      actionButton( inputId="runComp" , 
                    label="Start Computation" )
    ) , # end sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("theOutput")
    )
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end ui fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Parse data values out of data text:
  theData = reactive({
    yText = input$dataText
    y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(yText,"\\s+")[[1]]))
    if ( any(is.na(y)) | length(y) < 2 ) {
      y=c(-12.3, 45.6, 78.9) # arbitrary replacement values
      updateTextAreaInput( session ,
                           inputId="dataText" ,
                           value=paste(as.character(y),collapse=" ") )
    }
    return( y )
  }) 
  # Computation on data for using in slider update:
  upUI <- reactive({
    low = min( theData() )
    val = median( theData() )
    high = max( theData() )
    return( list( low=low , val=val , high=high ) )
  })
  # Update slider based on data values:
  observe({
    updateSliderInput( session , inputId="slider1" , 
                       min=upUI()$low , 
                       max=upUI()$high , 
                       value=upUI()$val )
  })

  # Debounce the slider value so it doesn't instantly trigger a cascade of long
  # computations
  sliderValue <- reactive({
    return( input$slider1 )
  }) %>% debounce(debounceDelay)

  # Compute output:
  textOut <- eventReactive(input$runComp, {
    req(theData(), sliderValue())
    Sys.sleep(3) # simulate lengthy computation time
    print(paste(Sys.time(), "Time-consuming computation..."))
    return( paste( "Time-consuming computation...
        Mean of data plus slider value: " ,
                   mean(theData()) + sliderValue() ) ) 
  })

  output$theOutput <- renderText({
    textOut()
  }) # end of renderText

} # end server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**Edit:** Here is a (time based) solution adressing the expected behaviour as described by @JohnK.Kruschke. I personally prefer the above solution (This might fail if the host PC is slowed down by external circumstances, nevertheless it worked during my tests).

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr) # for pipe operator, %>%, used with debounce().
debounceDelay = 2000 # milliseconds

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data affect Slider, both affect Subsequent Long Computation"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Data input:
      textAreaInput(
        inputId = "dataText" ,
        label = "Type data, then click Submit:" ,
        value = "10 20 30 40" ,
        width = "200px" ,
        height = "100px"
      ) ,
      p(actionButton(inputId = "dataSubmit" ,
                   label = "Submit Data")) ,
      # Slider input, to be updated by data:
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "slider1" ,
        label = HTML("Constant to Add to Mean of Data
                                (after debounce delay):") ,
        min=3000 , max=5000 , value=4000 ,
        round = FALSE ,
        step = 1 ,
        ticks = FALSE
      )
    ) ,
    # end sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(textOutput("theOutput"))
  ) # end sidebarLayout
) # end ui fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sliderUpdates <- reactiveValues(latestProgrammatic = Sys.time(), timeDiff = 0)

  # Parse data values out of data text:
  theData = reactive({
    input$dataSubmit# establish dependency on dataSubmit button
    yText = isolate(input$dataText) # remove dependency on dataText
    y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(yText, "\\s+")[[1]]))
    if (any(is.na(y)) | length(y) < 2) {
      y = c(-12.3, 45.6, 78.9) # arbitrary replacement values
      updateTextAreaInput(session ,
                          inputId = "dataText" ,
                          value = paste(as.character(y), collapse = " "))
    }
    return(y)
  })
  # Computation on data for using in slider update:
  upUI <- reactive({
    low = min(theData())
    val = median(theData())
    high = max(theData())
    return(list(
      low = low ,
      val = val ,
      high = high
    ))
  })
  # Update slider based on data values:
  observeEvent(upUI(), {
    sliderUpdates$latestProgrammatic <- Sys.time()
    print(paste("Programmatic slider update was triggered:" , sliderUpdates$latestProgrammatic))
    updateSliderInput(
      session ,
      inputId = "slider1" ,
      min = upUI()$low ,
      max = upUI()$high ,
      value = upUI()$val
    )
  })

  # Debounce the slider value so it doesn't instantly trigger a cascade of long
  # computations
  sliderValue <- reactive({
    latestUnkown <- Sys.time()
    print(paste("Slider was updated:" , latestUnkown))
    sliderUpdates$timeDiff <- latestUnkown - sliderUpdates$latestProgrammatic

    req(input$slider1)
    return(input$slider1)
  }) %>% debounce(debounceDelay)

  # Compute output:
  output$theOutput <- renderText({
    req(theData(), sliderValue(), req(isolate(sliderUpdates$timeDiff)))

    print(paste("Elapsed time since the last programmatic slider update:", isolate(sliderUpdates$timeDiff)))
    if(isolate(sliderUpdates$timeDiff) > 0.2){
      Sys.sleep(3) # simulate lengthy computation time
      return(
        paste(
          "Time-consuming computation...
        Mean of data plus slider value: " ,
          mean(theData()) + sliderValue()
        )
      )
    } else {
      NULL
    }

  }) # end of renderText

} # end server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately the version you posted still does the computation twice when the data are changed in the text area. I'm thinking perhaps to modify the computation so that it uses the value from upUI() unless the slider has been changed in which case use sliderValue(), but I'm not sure yet how to do that...

Comment: That is, in the computation use whichever is newer: the value from upUI() or the value from sliderValue(), if the updating of the slider doesn't then re-trigger the computation...

Comment: To be honest, if this were my application, I'd trigger the long running computation on pressing the button (taking into account whatever state both inputs currently have).

Comment: Please check my edit. Not sure if this is applicable for you - but in my eyes this follows a clear logic (adjust inputs, start computation after everything is set up).

Comment: Yeah, the logic of the "start computation" `actionButton` is something I considered too, and it's helpful to see it in operation - thank you for that! I suppose I could set up my complete app that way... I'll wait a while to see if anyone else has a different approach before marking this one as answered. Thank you again.

Comment: In the end it comes down to the question if it's posible to distinguish a programmatic update to the slider from a manual update. I currently don't see a solution for that - as you might have guessed when I was answering in the first place I simply misunderstood your question.

Comment: @JohnK.Kruschke, please check my edit. I found a solution to adress the originally requested behaviour.

Comment: That second solution is clever use of timing! While you were coming up with that second solution, I was busy adapting your first solution, and appended it to my original post just now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would solve this. Change this:

```
  observe({
    updateSliderInput( session , inputId="slider1" , 
                       min=upUI()$low , 
                       max=upUI()$high , 
                       value=upUI()$val )
  })
```

To this:

```
  observe({
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "slider1")
    updateSliderInput( session , inputId="slider1" , 
                       min=upUI()$low , 
                       max=upUI()$high , 
                       value=upUI()$val )
  }, priority = 100)
```

The `freezeReactiveinput()` call ensures that, for the rest of this reactive flush cycle, any attempt to access `input$slider1` will trigger the equivalent of `req(FALSE)` (silent abort of the currently executing output/observer). And `priority = 100` ensures that this observer (the one that freezes the value and calls `updateSliderInput`) will happen before any other outputs/observers.

Comment: Using the above with OPs initial code, when modifying the `textAreaInput` and clicking the `dataSubmit` button the "long running computation" is still executed twice. Am I missing something?